# Continously getting undefined error in React and amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm trying to perform a list query on a dynamo database in my react project  but I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: patients is undefined
render
C:/Health Project/nutzer-system/src/PatientComponents/listPatients.js:62

  59 | console.log(patients)
  60 | return (
  61 |     <div className={classes.root}>
> 62 |   <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={16}>
     | ^  63 |   {patients.map( patient => (
  64 |          <Grid key={patient.id} patient>
  65 |              <Card className={classes.card}>
```

here is a look at alittle more of my code

```
state = {
        patients: []
      }

      componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getPatients()
      }

      getPatients = () => {
        API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listPatients))
        .then(data => this.setState({patients: data.data.listPatients.patients}))
      };

  render(){
    const { classes } = this.props; 
    const { patients } = this.state;
    console.log(patients)
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={16}>
      {patients.map( patient => (
             <Grid key={patient.id} patient>
                 <Card className={classes.card}>
                   <CardContent>
                   <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                       {patient.Vorname}
                     </Typography>
                     <Typography component="p">
                       {patient.Nachname}
                     </Typography>
                     <Typography component="p">
                       {patient.Strasse}
                     </Typography>
```

If you need to see more code just say and I will add it in. I can't figure out how to resolve this. Any help in solving this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `data.data.listPatients.patients` is not `undefined`?

Comment: yes quite sure it isn't

Comment: what does `console.log(patients)` return?

Comment: it returns an array of the various elements in the database

Comment: I can't see the problem. Can you provide a bit more code please

Comment: Hi @Brian Le I just figured it out, you were right      data.data.listPatients.patients                                                      was undefined i changed patients to item      data.data.listPatients.items                                                         and it worked.

Comment: Alright mate good luck! :)

Comment: thanks for the help mate :)  you are life saver

Answer (score 1):

this.state.patients is populated asynchronously, which means you have to make sure it's default value is empty array, that way, `render()` won't get the runtime error even if you attempt patients.map. Think of it as `[].map` works but `undefined.map` doesn't. Try this:

replace

```
const { patients } = this.state;
```

with

```
const { patients = [] } = this.state;
```

Comment: His default state is an empty array

Comment: ah my bad, I didn't pay attention. So yeah we need to know what console.log(patients) shows.

Comment: I think this is correct, it will handle the case where `patients` gets updated to `undefined` in `getPatients`. It will override the initial empty array state